# select multiple category and subcategory joomla 3

Tags: select, components, joomla3.0

I write a component for Joomla 3. In my component I must select multiple category and subcategory.

My category comes from table that I create in database because my category is 
two-level.

How do I use the fields in the form that is beautiful and good?

Comment: welcome @user2279698, you should maybe provide some more details, about your database, and give a sample of your existing code

Answer (score 0):

There is no "pretty" way of doing this built into Joomla. You will have to build your own. Typically I would write out a bunch of checkboxes and allow the user to select the ones he wants.

In core Joomla you would use a select field with the multiple option selected. You can read about doing that here: http://blog.calebnance.com/joomla-3.0/saving-a-multi-select-field-in-a-custom-joomla-3.x-component.html